# how to select/deselect all checkboxes generated in loop when parent checkbox is checked

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('.parent').on('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.child[]').attr('checked',this.checked);
    });
});
</script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S No.</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="select1" id="select1" class="parent" /></th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Deal Type</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>   
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php $sql="select * from table_name where id='$id'";
      $result=mysql_query($sql); 
      $sn=1;
      while($show=mysql_fetch_array($result))
      { 
          $student=$show['student'];

      ?>
      <td><?php  echo $sn; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' class='child[]' id='check[]' value='".$student."'/>"; ?></td>
      <td>enddate</td>
      <td>View</td>
      <td>Edit</td>                                            
      <td>Delete</td>
      <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <?php $sn++ }}?>
```

Here, `checkbox-name=select1` is out of loop and it is parent checkbox. `checkbox-name=check` is actually an array of checkbox coming along with data from database. If there are 10 entries in database, 10 checkboxes will come. I want that if I check parent checkbox, then all checkboxes should get checked irrespective of numbers you can say, just like gmail. Also please tell where to place javascript/jquery. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I also moved the script tag out of the html table. Proper formatting can help to find issues. I can't find the closing `}` for the `while` loop, and the `tr` open tag also appears to be outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside your click callback would refer to the checkbox itself. So `$(this).find('.child[]')` will not find any elements.

Also note that the `class="index[]"` will not work with jQuery, so you would like to change that to `class="index"`. You can leave `name="index[]"` as it is.

If you want to look for elements inside the scope of the parent table (thus allowing you to have multiple structures of (un)check all), you would use:

```
$(function(){
  $('.parent').on('click',function(){
      $(this).parents('table').find('.child').attr('checked',this.checked);
  });
});
```

If you want to look for just all child nodes in the document, you would use:

```
$(function(){
  $('.parent').on('click',function(){
      $('.child').attr('checked',this.checked);
  });
});
```

Kind regards,

Arnoud

Comment: thank u arnoud ....can u tell me where to place this jquery..Is it in <head> along with other javasercript code or after the parent checbox code........I have kept the code u hane given in <head> but still not working...

Comment: sorry, sir but still not working....the child checkboxes are coming in loop but in jquery we have not mentioned that child is an array.Can u enlighten me concept because i am new in jquery....if u can refer me to something..i will be glad..thanking you...

Comment: See http://pastebin.com/uUEv7BYV for a working example on static data instead of mysql